# SQL Server: Text() in Xquery used to add delimiter in XML

Tags: sql-server

I have following existing code in one of the stored procedures to all delimiter `/` between error messages encounters in the validations:

```
;with delimiting_errors
        (Id,
        Delimited_Error_List)
        as
        (
        select
        e2.Id,
        '/' 
        + (select '  ' + Fn
                from Customer e
                where e.Id = e2.Id
                for xml path(''), type
                ).value('substring(text()[1],2)', 'varchar(max)') as Delimited_Error
        from Customer e2
        group by e2.Id
        )

SELECT * FROM delimiting_errors
```

Request you to please help me in understanding the command

```
value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)')
```

1. I tried to search about `text()`, but couldn't find exact documentation for the same.
2. Similarly, how substring function is working only on 2 parameters in `substring(text()[1], 2)`, which actually requires 3 parameter.

Please help me with the concept behind this command, also please help me with some resource to read about `Text()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is going on here:

`.value('substring(text()[1],2)', 'varchar(max)')`

- `value()` function to extract a specific value from the XML, and convert it to a SQL Server data type, in your case to `varchar(max)`
- `substring` is [XQuery substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178063.aspx), not SQL substring, here it returns substring starting at position 2
- `text()` function here retrieves the inner text from within the XML
- `[1]` suffix acts as an indexer, and fetches the first result matched

For more info read [XQuery Language Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx), it's like *"another language"* inside SQL.

Comment: @Shnugo I made mistake writing it returns 2 chars, of course it substring(string, starting_point), because I watched at substring(string, starting_point, length) definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
.value('substring(text()[1],2)', 'varchar(max)') as Delimited_Error
```

You use this XML-trick to concatenate values. In the beginning you add a double space `select '  ' + Fn`, this must be taken away for the beginning of the return string.

So, the `.value` returns the "substring" (XPath-Function!) of the inner text() starting at the index 2.

Find more information here: http://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/XML/XSL/XPath/Funktionen